# Is it possible to inject another chart data after init in dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have checkboxes and when my user checks one of them, I want to download json data series using ajax, and inject into a **dygraphs** instance. My data looks like this: `[{date: '2015-03-04 11:22:33.123, water_temp: 87},...]` and another data I want to inject as a second line graphs is: `[{date: '2015-03-04 11:22:33.123, oil_temp: 72},...]`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Post the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Daenarys: thanks for Your corrections. I haven't got any code unfortunately. I just tried to download the data series, combine with the previous dataset and destroy, reinitialize the dygraphs instance, but it is way too slow.

Comment: The data format dygraphs accepts is described [here](http://dygraphs.com/data.html). You'll have to massage your data to match it.

Comment: Afterall I found the updateOptions(); call, where the file: parameter accepts exactly the same data types like the constructor.